# Synchronized block in a HTTP Filter

Tags: java, synchronization

I have a doubt regarding the synchronizing block.

for example I have a code like below in an HTTPSESSIONFilter.

```
synchronized(request.getsession()){
  some operations();
}
```

Now for example I logged using a browser(say chrome) which will send around 100 calls to the server and its working as expected.

My doubt is if the chorme call is executing the synchronized block will the block firefox calls too ? In other words sessiona is doing some operation on it, will sessionb gets blocked because of sessiona ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Firefox and chrome will have different HTTP sessions. So `request.getSession()` returns different objects for chrome and firefox.

Comment: My Doubt is not that whether they are returning same session or different sessions.For example the calls are blocked on chrome by synchronized block, and if a new call from firefox is coming, will it get blocked or continue with the execution of the block ?

Comment: It will continue execution, because `synchronized` acquires monitor of object. You have two session -> two objects. Firefox call will acquire monitor of second object.